# Why I can not login to magento backend using google chrome

Tags: php, magento, google-chrome, authentication, magento-1.7

I am using  magento community edition 1.7.0.2.I am not able to login to back end of magento.I know this problem can be because of chrome not accepting cookies.
But how to fix that please help.
Thanks

Comment: Hi though I accepted the very non technical answer which worked for me as a beginner,Please go through other answers also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple solution is to do the installation using Opera browser and use it to log in because it saves the cookies itself. It works!

Answer (score 38):

If you **enabled the https for the Magento admin panel**, then make sure to set "**NO**"  for the option "**Use HTTP Only" under System->configuration->web->Session and Cookie Management**."

If you have access to the database then open the table "**core_config_data**" and search for the Path "**web/cookie/cookie_httponly**" and set the value to "0".

Make sure to delete the var/cache folder. Now try to login to Magento admin panel. Mostly you can now. If not post your issue in this thread.

So this "Not able to login Magento admin panel" issue **mostly relates to the Magento cookies settings**. So don't get worried if you encounter this tiny issue. With the list of answers in this thread you can easily sort this out in a few minutes time.

Comment: For anyone coming to this question, this should be the first answer you try.

Comment: @Haijerome With your said way, don't you think that, that may lead a chance for XSS vulnerability. I am curious to know as I faced the same and was trying to go with your mentioned way
https://blog.codinghorror.com/protecting-your-cookies-httponly/

Answer (score 31):

There are two solutions for this, either one will work:

- Change the cookie lifetime configuration.Go to backend -> Sytem -> Configuration -> Web -> Session and Cookie Management
  Set cookie lifetime to 86400 and save it .

[image: see here]

- Go to app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php file within your magento directory.

Find the code:

```
session_set_cookie_params(
$this->getCookie()->getLifetime(),
$this->getCookie()->getPath(),
$this->getCookie()->getDomain(),
$this->getCookie()->isSecure(),
$this->getCookie()->getHttponly()
);
```

**or**

```
// session cookie params
$cookieParams = array(
    'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
    'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
    'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
    'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
    'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
);
```

and replace with

```
session_set_cookie_params(
$this->getCookie()->getLifetime(),
$this->getCookie()->getPath()
//$this->getCookie()->getDomain(),
//$this->getCookie()->isSecure(),
//$this->getCookie()->getHttponly()
);
```

**or**

```
// session cookie params
$cookieParams = array(
    'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
    'path'     => $cookie->getPath()
//  'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
//  'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
//  'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
);
```

After this save the file.

Comment: Please do not comment the lines stated above in core files

Answer (score 4):

This so far is the best solution rather than changing the code elsewhere http://iamtheshadowonthesun.blogspot.com/2012/10/magento-cannot-login-to-admin-panel.html

Using phpMyAdmin, in your magento database, look for the core_config_data table and click it. Click the "Search" tab.  Then on the "path" column set the operator to LIKE %...% and the Value to cookie and click the "Go" button to search.

After searching, set the value of web/cookie/cookie_path, web/cookie/cookie_domain, web/cookie/cookie_httponly, and web/browser_capabilities/cookies to NULL

Answer (score 3):

what worked for me is what Haijerome, unfortunatelly I can't login into the backend to change the config.
This is what I execute whenever I install a new fresh magento:

```
insert into core_config_data(scope, scope_id, path, value) values("default", "0", "web/cookie/cookie_httponly", "0");
```

then:

```
rm -Rf var/cache/mage--*
```

Answer (score 2):

Our Chrome users were unable to add items to their cart... changing the Cookie Lifetime to the recommended 86400 fixed it.

Magento Community 1.7

Thank you!

Jeff

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that chrome isnt storing the login cookie, this can be seen by looking at the cookies in chrome | settings | content | advanced | all cookies and site data

there's probably a number of reasons why this can happen, cookie lifetime for sure is one of them..

personally I encountered this problem when running magento in localhost / on a virtual machine and connecting from a browser on the same machine.  specifically the problem seems to be that chrome will not store cookies if the domain name is not qualified.  so if your domain name is 'http://localhost/magento' or 'http://somename/magento' chrome will not store the cookie and consequently you will not be able to login

here's the fix:

to keep this simple i'm sticking to the example where magento is running on localhost.  the same trick will work if magento is running on a vm and you're accessing from localhost, but you need to modify the hosts file on both guest os and client in such a case.  (and remember that the guest ip can change so from time to time you need to update the hosts file on the host)

first choose your domainname.  it's only in local so you dont need to register.  i'm choosing 'dansmagentodev.com'.  then in magento | system | web  modify baseurl in both secure and unsecure to be 
http://dansmagentodev.com/magento/

next, in the same place, modify the session cookie management 'cookie domain' to be 'dansmagentodev.com'

next we need to configure your system to know that dansmagentodev.com is really localhost.  we do this via the hosts file.  on windows this file is in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts. your virus checker will probably try to stop you modifying it (for good reason, disable virus checker while you make the modification).  then add the line
127.0.0.1 dansmagentodev.com

And now log in from chrome.

Comment: just in case; if you break your configuration doing this (which can happen if the url you enter into magento | system differs from that in your hosts file) then you can fix by manually editing the sql tables, look in core_config_data

Answer (score 2):

My problem was the fact that the server I was running was an Ubuntu fresh install with very little server maintenance configuration.

It had not updated it's date & time and it was 3h behind.

This made cookies received by Chrome to look as if they were already expired so Chrome discarded them.

Answer (score 0):

If on firefox works. Then the problem is cookies on chrome,  try to clear your chrome's cookie.

Comment: I tried your solution but it does not help.It is working on firefox. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: can u give me the solution how you got it fixed?

Comment: if you run magento on localhost, Go to app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php file within your magento directory. session_set_cookie_params(
$this->getCookie()->getLifetime(),
$this->getCookie()->getPath()
//$this->getCookie()->getDomain(),
//$this->getCookie()->isSecure(),
//$this->getCookie()->getHttponly()
);

Comment: Better not to comment in core files.create local copy of file then comment the above lines in Varien.php