# Magento admin login not working in chrome but works fine for firefox

Tags: magento, google-chrome

I am just a newbie to the magento. I have installed magento on my localhost. After all the setup when I used the admin page to login I can't able to login in chrome browser even with my right username and password. But when I am trying to login in firefox there is no problem. So can some one really help me here to solve the problem?

Comment: Follow this link
[Why I can not login to magento backend using google chrome][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328366/why-i-can-not-login-to-magento-backend-using-google-chrome/15181463?noredirect=1#15181463

Comment: You can get the answer from [HERE][1]


  [1]: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6426/magento-1-7-0-2-cannot-login-to-admin-locally

Comment: I'm facing this same issue, check my question please http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/85958/magento-admin-login-issue

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I think there is the problem with `session cookie` with the chrome browser.
So just go through this directory
`/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php` file
and comment out the line from 85 to 92 in magento (1.7.2 for my case). Like this

```
    // session cookie params
   /* $cookieParams = array(
        'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
        'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
        'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
        'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
        'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
    );
  */
```

after that try to make login from your backend. Hopefully you can make login with chrome. This will definitely help you. If you are still facing the problem then just reply me.

Comment: I had given the same answer as given by you in the link shared by me in this post.But I don't know why my answer was deleted on that post.

Comment: I solved the login issue in my live site using this answer. Is it right to use this solution in live server or this solution is for localhost only?

Comment: Files in *app/code/core* should never be modified, only extended. If you were to ever upgrade your site, your changes will be overwritten.

Comment: I was experiencing this issue on a client's site as well, and filling in the Cookie Domain resolved the issue. I also filled in "/" (no quotations) for the Cookie path.

Comment: I don't know why this answer is getting such a high score, it's dead wrong to do this. Just change your cookie path like Meogi mentioned.

Comment: Never ever makes changes to Magento Core files. You just need to update cookie domain. This is a good resource http://blog.philwinkle.com/i-cant-login-to-magento-admin/

Comment: It is very weird that the answer is to patch 3rd party code directly in our system. By doing this, usually we sacrifice the maintainability aspect.

Comment: @NewUser Never modify core files

Comment: **I DONT KNOW WHY** but inspite of worked with Mageto since last 5 months, I still come here to see how to build **Basic config file** because I forget this a lot :)

Comment: This article explains the variety of reason and method to fix the solution. http://ersinfosystems.com/magento-admin-login-is-not-working/

Answer (score 18):

try using 127.0.0.1 when you set up magento in localhost. I have also encounter same problem, that's the solution a have made and it works fine.

Comment: This work for me, and I prefer this, becouse no need to change any things in the code.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer instead of commenting out the core files.. Thank u for ur solution

Answer (score 5):

From `System -> Configuration -> General -> Web`, set Unsecure and Secure Base URL with IP Address. And try to login again.

Answer (score 4):

GO to File at this location :- app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php

And commenting out the following (it's lines 85 to 102);

```
// session cookie params
$cookieParams = array(
    'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
    'path'     => $cookie->getPath()//,
    //'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
    //'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
    //'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
);

//if (!$cookieParams['httponly']) {
//    unset($cookieParams['httponly']);
//    if (!$cookieParams['secure']) {
//        unset($cookieParams['secure']);
//        if (!$cookieParams['domain']) {
//            unset($cookieParams['domain']);
//        }
//    }
//}
```

And use your credentials to logged in. Hope that should works for you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Magento sees `cookie_domain` on `core_config_data` table when you try to login. If it is diffrent from your domain, you can not enter your admin panel, just refreshing the page, no error comes up.

Open `core_config_data` table from your database and search or filter the `path` column for `web/cookie/cookie_domain` and change it to null or your domain.

Answer (score 1):

When it happens with me, the problems was because I make a directory move but the .HTACCESS files of main content was not moved to new path.

Check if your .htaccess file is in main content.

Comment: you answer is right, and I think that modifying the .htaccess file better than modifying the code of magento core

Answer (score 0):

just apply the comment here...
file location : \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php

```
/*
// session cookie params
    $cookieParams = array(
        'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
        'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
        'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
        'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
        'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
    );
  */
```

Answer (score 0):

login as admin with internet explorer or other broswer. flush all caches.. And you will be able to log in using chrome . You can login in without having to modify any code

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Magento 1.9, the file must be slightly different:
/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php

```
 $cookieParams = array(
        'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
        'path'     => $cookie->getPath()/*,
        'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
        'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
        'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()*/
    );

    /*if (!$cookieParams['httponly']) {
        unset($cookieParams['httponly']);
        if (!$cookieParams['secure']) {
            unset($cookieParams['secure']);
            if (!$cookieParams['domain']) {
                unset($cookieParams['domain']);
            }
        }
    }*/
```

Comment: I have tried the newuser solution and that worked perfectly. It'd be great if you can provide some more information about your answer. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

It’s also important that you have a form key present, otherwise your form won’t get processed.

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my **simple solution** that helped me in the same situation. Try it for *60 seconds* of your time.

In **Google Chrome**, in **Developer Tools** (right-click on any page element and select Inspect Element), go to the **Resources -> Cookies tab**. **Delete** the extra cookie for your original domain. Or set your base url domain to something else, or change the port.

Answer (score 0):

As the accepted answer pointed out, the problem lies with chrome when accessing Magento on a localhost. Wrap the code in the`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php` with the following snippet, and the session parameter array will be only reset if you are on localhost (IP'127.0.0.1' or '::1').

```
// SNIPPET Part 1: add this before the original array definition
// -----------------------------------------------------------

if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', '::1'))) {
    $cookieParams = array();
} else {

    // here comes the original code, thats what you should
    // look for but not touch
    // -------------------------------------------------------

    // session cookie params
    $cookieParams = array(
        'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
        'path' => $cookie->getPath(),
        'domain' => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
        'secure' => $cookie->isSecure(),
        'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
    );

// SNIPPET Part 2: add the closing bracket
// ------------------------------------------

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Magento ver. `1.14.2.1`

changing varien.php did not solve my problem.

entering `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` in Dashboard configuration Web Base URL solved my problem.

I can still enter localhost in the url and it automatically redirects it to the ip format url.

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2

Instead of localhost on your WAMP please use http://127.0.0.1

> {folder
>   path}\magento2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Session.php

Go to & Comment as mentioned

```
 public static function rememberUntil($seconds = 0)
    {
        if (self::$_unitTestEnabled) {
            self::regenerateId();
            return;
        }

        $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();

        session_set_cookie_params(
            $seconds,
            //$cookieParams['path'],
            //$cookieParams['domain'],
            //$cookieParams['secure']
            );

        // normally "rememberMe()" represents a security context change, so should use new session id
        self::regenerateId();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Having session/cookie problems with webkit browsers (e.g. Chrome) in Magento? Go to ***System -> Configuration -> Web -> Session Cookie Management and set “Use HTTP Only”*** to no. Have fun.

Comment: This *sounds* like it involves disabling XSS protection across your entire browser. That's kind of a bad idea.