# Cannot login to magento admin when used custom admin url

Tags: php, magento

I am using magento 1.9.1. I want to change the admin url path. I followed both the procedure shown in [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40620/correct-way-to-change-the-magento-1-9-admin-url) . I am able to change the url successfully but could not login. It is not even showing any error message. Everywhere I see the same procedures for changing the admin url. No one mentioned about the problem I got. Cleared the cache many times. Can anyone tell what exactly is the procedure to change the admin url in magento 1.9.1?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just change in app/etc/local.xml the tag admin-routers-adminhtml-args-frontName attribute to what you want. then manually delete /var/cache content and everything should work properly. Also, try the following url to login http://yourdomain.com/index.php/your-new-admin-path

Comment: Yeah that's what I did. The url is working but I could not login.

Comment: Try with different browser. If that works, you have another issue that needs to be solved. Luckily stackoverflow solves that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491819/magento-admin-login-not-working-in-chrome-but-works-fine-for-firefox

Comment: I tried chrome and mozilla. The result is same. It simply redirects to

/index.php/MYCUSTOMADMIN/index/index/key/aae1892949ae90bbb379555c3e7beb16/

Comment: Check /var/logs or /var/report

Comment: Just checked. No reports, no error logs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77312/discussion-between-raghuveer999-and-aki).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely a cookie or cache issue.   I work for an agency and I run into this alot when switching from a dev site to a production site.   Here's what I'd recommend you try:

1. Manually remove cache (magento_root/var/cache/* and magento_root/var/full_page_cache if on enterprise).
2. Either clear your browser cookies or do it via dev tools.  In chrome, More Tools > Developer tools > select resources > cookies > right mouse click and hit delete all cookies.

Never failed for me.

Comment: I tried deleting cache every time. And I use incognito mode for browsers.

Comment: It is working only with the url with the text 'admin' inside it. Ex: amin123, 123admin, abcadminde etc. :) but not any other.

Comment: Hey Raghuveer, did you clear the cache directly from the file system or did you use the clear cache buttons in Magento?   I find that sometimes the cache gets "stuck" and you have to actually do it from command line sometimes.....

Comment: cont...  Also, if you are using reddis cache or something of that nature, you'll want to click both the flush magento cache and the flush cache storage button.