# Can't login to Magento admin panel

Tags: magento, authentication, admin, backend, magento-1.9

For test and development, I duplicated our Magento shop to a sub-domain.

```
mysql -u root -p -e "USE bitnami_magento; UPDATE core_config_data SET value ='http://subdomain.site.com/' WHERE core_config_data.path = 'web/unsecure/base_url'; UPDATE core_config_data SET value ='https://subdomain.site.com/' WHERE core_config_data.path = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

Everything works, but not the admin Login. On the login page we get it. After entering my user name and password we don't log in. Login error message ("invalid password", etc.) ISN`T being displayed.

We are using **1.9.0.1**

Removing cache files ...

```
sudo rm -r /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/cache/*
sudo rm -r /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/session/*
```

.. and restarting Apache ..

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

.. Does not help.

Please any advice - what could be the reason?

Comment: UPD: It works on the browser FireFox. Problems logging in Admin Panel (Backend) with Opera and Chrome. Also, there is no problem with login in other computers with different browsers. Perhaps the problem is "session cookie". Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If everything works on the front end like you said, and you just can't log into the admin, most probably you have the original adminhtml cookie pointing to your original domain, (www.site.com) and an extra adminhtml cookie for your development domain (subdomain.site.com).

In Chrome, in Developer Tools (right-click on any page element and select Inspect Element), go to the Resources -> Cookies tab. Delete the extra cookie for your original domain. Or set your base url domain to something else, or change the port.

Comment: Many thanks
Your advice was the most accurate for me!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different web browser, specific try with both Firefox and Chrome. If this resolves it then question is duplicate of [Magento admin login not working in chrome but works fine for firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491819/magento-admin-login-not-working-in-chrome-but-works-fine-for-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Using a different browser won't help because the error is pretty clear.

Try checking the system log and exception log and also, if you have good MySQL skills, have a look on Magento users table in database and make sure that the database is imported properly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your local.xml file for db configuration.
Is db name host name and every thing is fine. If no please do so.

Another thing after moving have you edited core_config_data table. if not please edit core_config_data table by changing the web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url to match the new domain name by altering the value column for both records.

Hope It will help you.