# Magento 1.9 admin login not working in Chrome but working in Firefox?

Tags: php, mysql, magento

Magento 1.9 admin login not working in Chrome but working in Firefox?

Comment: Are you working on  localhost? Is your url structure is like  http://localhost/magento/admin?

Comment: in this case you use 127.0.0.1/magento instead of localhost/magento in core_config_data

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento admin login not working in chrome but works fine for firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491819/magento-admin-login-not-working-in-chrome-but-works-fine-for-firefox)

Answer (score 4):

Go to This directory
/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php file and comment out the line from 95 to 101 working fine.

```
    // session cookie params
   /* $cookieParams = array(
        'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
        'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
        'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
        'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
        'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
    );
  */
```

Comment: Magento core files must not be changed.