# Magento 1.9 - empty cart page using localhost

Tags: magento, shopping-cart, magento-1.9

I'm using Magento CE 1.9 and my cart keeps emptying when I click on the cart page.  This only happens on localhost and is not a problem in production (which uses SSL).  Here's what happens:

1. Add a product to the shopping cart
2. Click continue shopping
3. Product is in the mini-cart
4. Navigate to the cart page
5. Application immediately render the empty cart page (and mini-cart is empty as well)

I've tried changing the increasing the cookie lifetime to 1 day and setting Validate HTTP_USER_AGENT to yes.  What else can I do?

Comment: Are you face this issue in chrome?

Comment: @Meenakshi - Yes!  For the localhost environment, I don't get the empty cart page on FF... just on Chrome.  But, in production, I don't get the problem in either browser.  Do you know why?  And, how can I resolve?  I prefer to use Chrome to debug in my local environment.

Comment: this may help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491819/magento-admin-login-not-working-in-chrome-but-works-fine-for-firefox

Comment: @Vee Try ip address instead of localhost like http://127.0.0.1/mysite/     Are you able to login to your localhost site?