# Login failing magento admin panel from chrome, IE

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am playing around magento-1.7, where after installing the source from mozilla
i could login to admin panel from mozilla where as i am unable to login to the 
admin panel neither from chrome nor from IE.

so, any have any idea how whats failing..?

Comment: does url http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/admin working?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328366/why-i-can-not-login-to-magento-backend-using-google-chrome

Comment: Thank u both for responding,..

@Muk: this helped me get over the problem,. thanks again.