# magento admin panel, how can i fix "Access denied"

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

when I log into my admin panel, I get up this message "Access denied"

How can I fix the problem? I can not access anything without logging in?

Comment: Did you try resetting your admin password in the database directly ?

Comment: no, what is the difference?

Comment: Lamp stack magento issues are ridiculous, for such basic features. So much time configuring obscure things that should just work out of the box. LAMP and magento are so old, yet how have they not addressed basic issues like this yet?

Answer (score 7):

When this problem occurs after adding a new user, the problem could be that no role for that user is selected.

If you can still login with another user, you can simply select a role for the new user and the problem will be solved.

To select a role, go to: System > Permissions > Users > [Select User] > User Role (tab).

Comment: Magic - this fixed mine. I just went into the table admin_role and copied a previous row, substituting my User ID.

Comment: You did not explain how to select a role

Comment: Extended my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you have lost access to you admin page only, then you can go into your database and change the password by following method

1. Enter into your database and search for `admin_user` table
2. In `admin_user` table click the edit button on the row who you feel is the admin.
3. In the password field, select the function as MD5 form the drop-down in the function column.
4. Now in the value field, type the password and hit Go.

This way you can reset the password and make sure you are entering the correct password an d username.
(the above method I am suggesting assuming that you cannot even enter the admin page)

Another method I am suggesting assuming that your access is denied for some particular module.

1. Enter in to your magento files and navigate to the file named `system.xml`
2. See how many groups you are having in the `system.xml` file as following

`

```
   <system> 
   <children>
    <config>
    <children>
    <my_group_name>
    <title>My Group Name</title>
    </my_group_name>
    <second_group_name>
    <title>My Second Group Name</title>
    </second_group_name>
    </children>
    </config>
    </children>
    </system>
```

Here I am showing two groups

3.Navigate to the `config.xml` file and add both groups names as children in `config.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
       ...
       ..
       .
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        ...
        ..
        .
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        ...
        ..
        .
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            ...
            ..
            .
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <MyCompany_MyModule>
                            <title>My Module</title>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        </MyCompany_MyModule>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <my_group_name>
                                            <title>My Group Name</title>
                                        </my_group_name>
                                        <second_group_name>
                                            <title>My Second Group Name</title>
                                        </second_group_name>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            ...
            ..
            .
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>  
    <global>
        ...
        ..
        .
    </global>
</config>
```

Source http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-access-denied-in-admin-of-custom-module/

hope this is helpful

Comment: You'll also see the permission denied thing if your config.xml is missing that <adminhtml> node. Worth noting.

Comment: There is no "admin_user" table, do you mean "mageadmin_user" ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1)Are you entering correct username and password?

2)If you are facing problem when you are trying to login using chrome.(try url like 127.0.0.1/yourmagento)

OR try this link
[why-i-can-not-login-to-magento-backend-using-google-chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328366/why-i-can-not-login-to-magento-backend-using-google-chrome)

To reset admin password.Go to phpmyadmin and run following command.

```
UPDATE `admin_user` SET `password` = MD5('PASSWORD') WHERE `username` = 'USERNAME';
```

Still facing any problem add comment.I will try to help you.

Comment: @Max Are you still facing problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the cache folder.

\magento\var\cache

Delete all files and folders.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add an entry for my user in **mageadmin_role** and it only worked after I selected "U" instead of "G" as the role