# magento admin panel not login using chrome but working fine in firefox

Tags: magento, google-chrome

I am just a new in magento. I have installed magento on my localhost. After installing I tried to login as admin i can't be able to login using Google chrome browser but in Firefox its working fine . Any one can help me to sort out this problem? 
thanks in advance

Comment: hello clear browser cache

Comment: cache cleared but still facing same issue

Comment: @ShakirBlouch  try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328366/why-i-can-not-login-to-magento-backend-using-google-chrome

Comment: @ShakirBlouch Do not make changes in core files as suggested by others. Chrome is not considering localhost as valid domain.

Comment: Don't use `localhost` as a base url. Use `127.0.0.1` instead. That way you don't need to modify the core code.

Comment: @Muk Yes, I  made the change in core files and its working fine now. thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php file within your magento directory and around line number 88 find the below code and comment those below lines

Change

```
$cookieParams = array(
'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
'path' => $cookie->getPath(),
'domain' => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
'secure' => $cookie->isSecure(),
'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
);
```

To

```
$cookieParams = array(
'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
'path' => $cookie->getPath(),
// 'domain' => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
// 'secure' => $cookie->isSecure(),
// 'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
);
```

And now try to login with your credentials to logged in. Hope that should works for you!!!

Comment: If this solution workes for you,please accpet this answer by upvote.

Comment: Change the magento's core is not a solution.

Comment: @WellingtonLorindo `Change the magento's core is not a solution.` any other sol?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend editing your Magento database and removing the following lines from the core_config_data table:

web/cookie/cookie_path

web/cookie/cookie_domain

web/cookie/cookie_httponly

To find these values you can use the following SELECT command:

SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE "%web/cookie%";

Thereafter,

DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE config_id in (xx,xx,xx) where X is the config_id reference of the core_config_data table.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem and simple trick worked for me. Also this is for people who cannot access the dashboard on **Google Chrome**. If you can please carry on by working on Mozilla Firefox then please do so because I guess this issue is not persistent on Mozilla firefox.

So the solution for chrome is:

Goto **System->Configuration->Web**. Expand the **Unsecure and Secure** tab. Change the Base URL to `http://127.0.0.1/[Your folder name]` if your using localhost or change it to your Site URL through which you are accessing the frontend. I had to **login twice** to get the Dashboard since when I entered the details for the first time, it just refreshes and comes back to the same page as you mentioned it as looping. Please try and let me know whether it worked for you too.