# magento need to change language on every page when other than language is selected

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system

I have problem while language translation in Magento 1.8
I have added 3 language English[default language], French and Arabian.

Everything is fine..

But when I choose any other language than default language and click any links, after refreshing the page, I mean in next page the language will be default only, means English. Is selected. Again i need to choose the language.

Where I am missing any settings for this problem??

Comment: seems it's cookies issue, have try on different browsers?

Comment: Yes!!! You are right Ansyori. Thanks

Comment: How to solve this problem?

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328366/why-i-can-not-login-to-magento-backend-using-google-chrome