# The cookie alert for allowing customers to save the cookies repeats and navigates to Enable Cookies page in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, magento, magento-1.8

I am new to **Magento** and I have just setup Magento 1.8.1 with the sample data. I was going through the user guide of Magento CE 1.8.1 and came to know that Cookie restriction mode should be set to **Yes** because of European Union Privacy and Electronic Communications Directive and its amendment. But i am facing a issue now which I am unable to resolve. After changing the settings to Yes, I refreshed my site and I got the **Allow Cookie Alert Box**. I clicked **Allow** and I was directed to the **Enable Cookies** page. I again clicked allow on that page and was directed back to the same page as if it just refreshed. I am embedding screenshots for clear understanding:

[image: home page - magento]

[image: Enable cookie page - magento]

the **first one is the home page** and the **second one is the enable cookie page**.

Few changes what I did was, I changed **System -> Config -> General -> Web -> use http only to No**. I did this because I was getting errorless Login page when I was trying to login on the backend in Google chrome and this was one of the solutions available on stack overflow.  But I reverted this back to yes when I came to know that this makes the site vulnerable to attacks. That's why I did some changes in the **varien.php** file as described in the second solution of [Why I can not login to magento backend using google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328366/why-i-can-not-login-to-magento-backend-using-google-chrome) by a user named **AKT**. Also, I had set the **Cookie Restriction Mode to YES**. Does anyone have a solution to this? This is only happening in Google Chrome.