# Magento admin panel not working in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, magento

I installed latest version of magneto in my Localhost but when i opened this on my server, the admin panel not redirect in chrome but on Firefox it works very well.. What the reason of this situation [image]

[image]

Comment: Go to `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php` and comment out the lines `domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
            'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
            'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()` .It might be due to that

Comment: This is for windows or Ubuntu system, Iam asking because i am using Ubuntu

Comment: This is not related to ubuntu or windows. I think it is related to cookies, the browser is not able to create cookie which is required for logins in magento. try it and see

Comment: And for magento you can go to http://magento.stackexchange.com/ which is dedicated for magento

Comment: use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` in your url, so you need to change as well as in DB

Comment: zamil i used your refereed work but still same problem

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328366/why-i-can-not-login-to-magento-backend-using-google-chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced similar issues when using magento and localhost urls.  Try the following steps:

1. Visit

   chrome://net-internals/#dns

in your chrome browser and then click the "clear host cache" button.

2. Make sure you clear your browser cookies for localhost.
3. Clear your magento cache (just empty the var/cache folder)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may work:

Go to admin of your store from Mozila >system>configuration > General> Web >Session Cookies Management>

Set

Cookies lifetime: 0
Cookies Path : /
Cookie Domain: http://www.yourdoamin.com
Use HTTP Only: Yes
Cookie Restriction Mode: No

It may work.