# Magento Login issue with iPhone iPad (Safari) since two weeks knowing that I was able to login before

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, magento, authentication

I have an issue to login in my Magento dashboard with my Apple devices (iphone 6 and iPad) which occurred 2 weeks ago.
**What is strange is that last month I had no issue to connect to Magento** thus I used the saved backup of my website back at the time before the issue occurred but the issue still remain.
Then I browsed over several discussions on that topic such as:
- [Link 1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31933/customer-login-doesnt-work-in-1-9),
- [Link 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52088/cant-login-with-safari-on-ipad-magento-1-8) (related to system->configuration->general->web->session cookie management),
- [Link 3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/49134/customers-couldnt-login-from-safari-in-magento-1-9),
But none of them help me to solve my login issue with Apple devices only.

If anyone has an idea please let me know. Thank you for your help.

Comment: post your code of what you've tried

Comment: @joel which magento version you are using? and this issue is only on admin or facing same on front end too.

Comment: @urfusion I am using Magento 1.8.1, this issue occurred only on admin page

Comment: @johnny5 everything mentioned in the referred links

Comment: @Joel : have you made any changes in core files?

Comment: admin is working on http or https?

Comment: there is a answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328366/why-i-can-not-login-to-magento-backend-using-google-chrome
you can try that

Comment: @urfusion Thank you I am looking at it now I will keep you inform!

Comment: @urfusion admin should work on https, and I made changes before in core files but I put back the former backup. I will try the solution given in your link, but it seems that their issue was with Google Chrome not with Safari so not sure it would solve but I will give a try now

Comment: @urfusion I have just finished to test the solution with the 32 and 29 recommendations but they did not work for me....

Comment: clear your device cache and cookies.

Comment: @urfusion I have cleared my cache for each of my tests but did not work. I also cleared my browser but nothing change.

Comment: in that case check your log and console for errors

Comment: In the log from var\log\system.log I have those following message:
2015-09-25T20:55:53+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: httponly  in /home/Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 96
2015-09-25T20:55:53+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: secure  in /home/Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 98
2015-09-25T20:55:53+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: domain  in /home/Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 100

Comment: And below the code of the referred Varien.php lines (from line 96 to 104):
        if (!$cookieParams['httponly']) {
            unset($cookieParams['httponly']);
            if (!$cookieParams['secure']) {
                unset($cookieParams['secure']);
                if (!$cookieParams['domain']) {
                    unset($cookieParams['domain']);
                }
            }
        }

Comment: I have also another error message that comes along with:
2015-09-25T20:55:47+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: Entity: line 7: parser error : Premature end of data in tag html line 1  in /home/Site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/AdminNotification/Model/Feed.php on line 173

Comment: And below the line 173 of the Feed.php if it can help (lines 172 to 177):
        try {
            $xml  = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }

Comment: @Joel : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43899/troubleshooting-notice-undefined-index-httponly-secure-domain

Comment: @urfusion Thank you for the link but I don't see how to fix my issue as the code they mentioned as "This can't happen:" is what I have in my code

Comment: // session cookie params
$cookieParams = array(
'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
);

        if (!$cookieParams['httponly']) {
            unset($cookieParams['httponly']);
            if (!$cookieParams['secure']) {
                unset($cookieParams['secure']);
                if (!$cookieParams['domain']) {
                    unset($cookieParams['domain']);
                }
            }
        }

Comment: At last i just want to say Whyn't you go for dubbing code

Comment: Sorry what is dubbing code?
I had commented the code related to the domain, secure, and httponly but that does not work.
Beside for another error line related to the Feed.php I found the following link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31497/system-log-errors-warning-simplexmlelement-construct that suppose to breakdown the error path but somehow it couldn't work.

Comment: @Joel check the logging step by step. put `die('here');` in your login files. so you can check which code is causing this issue.

Comment: in which login files should I put the "die('here');"?